# Create framework within framework

Tags: swift, frameworks

i got some problem when i trying to include framework within framework. i try to make subframework in swift language. when i run in simulator  work perfectly but in device i have error “Reason: no suitable image found. Did find:”

the following is an error message:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/xxx.framework/xxx Referenced from:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81D1C716-915E-4DCA-893D-F934D56C8BAD/customDemo.app/Frameworks/custom.framework/custom
>   Reason: no suitable image found. Did find:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81D1C716-915E-4DCA-893D-F934D56C8BAD/customDemo.app/Frameworks/custom.framework/Frameworks/xxx.framework/xxx:
>   mmap() error 1 at address=0x00169000, size=0x000E8000 segment=__TEXT
>   in Segment::map() mapping
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/81D1C716-915E-4DCA-893D-F934D56C8BAD/customDemo.app/Frameworks/custom.framework/Frameworks/xxx.framework/xxx

Comment: i fix it by build all sub framework to universal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to submit an app to the App Store with a framework embedded inside another framework. All frameworks must be inside the main app bundle's `Frameworks` folder. This does not mean you cannot link one framework against another, though. Just specify framework B inside framework A's `Link Binary With Libraries` build phase, and don't embed it.

Comment: i fix it by build all sub framework to universal, but i'm not sure my app is allowed to submit an app to the App Store.